# Vue - how to show an array of data in a table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a component that, on page load, executes a request to my backend, receives some data and shows this data on a vuetify-datatable. I managed to get the data, but my table won't show it, as it is just empty.

Here is the component:

```
<template>
  <v-simple-table dark>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">
            Asset
          </th>
          <th class="text-left">
            Total
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="item in balances"
          :key="item.asset">
          <td>{{ item.asset }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
</template>


<script>

var balancesArr = []

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/binance/getbalance')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    balancesArr = data
    console.log(balancesArr)
  })

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        balances: balancesArr,
      }
    },
}

</script>
```

Here is `main.js`:

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.js";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import storePlugin from "./vuex/vuex_store_as_plugin";
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(storePlugin);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And the html file:

```
<div id="app">
        <app></app>
    </div>
```

I successfully see the data being printed on my console, but nothing shows on the table. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Just declare `balances` as empty array in `data`:  `data: () => ({ balances: [] }) `. This will make it reactive and when it changes (after you get the data), the template will be notified about the change.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried this but got an undefined error on balances

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific than *"got an undefined error on balances"*. It can mean way too many things.

Comment: What i mean is that the error is that balance is undefined: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: balances is not defined

Comment: Oh, the problem is you're fetching outside the instance. You have to fetch after the component is mounted. If you do it before, you might get the response before the component is mounted, so there's no place to put the response. Of course, you could save it and then place it on component in `mounted()`. However, the most common way of doing it is placing the `fetch()` inside `mounted()`.

Comment: Yeah i'm getting that i should do it the other way. I come from JQuery, just new to Vue and i'm feeling overwhelmed to say the least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226232/discussion-between-tao-and-jayk23).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Blockquote

You can use life-cycle hook `mounted` to fetch data on initial page load.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      balances: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/binance/getbalance')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.balances = data
        })
    }
  }
}
```

you can also use `created` to fetch data on initial page created is executed before mounted for reference [enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle) e.g.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      balances: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/binance/getbalance')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.balances = data
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this, but the table is still empty

Comment: can you put console log at line `this.balances = data` and see you getting data

Comment: Yes, i tried to add a console.log but it doesn't get triggered

Comment: I updated mine, here is what i got: [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly,  [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly. I'm trying to understand what triggers those errors

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you're not using vue correctly:

```
<script>



export default {
    created() {

      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/binance/getbalance')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => {
         this.balances = data
        
       })
    },
    data () {
      return {
        balances: [],
      }
    },
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very possible i'm using it wrong, i just got started to Vue and i'm trying to wrap my head around it. I tried this, but i'm still getting the table empty

Comment: @Tomer, as you can see, it is less important to be the first to answer. It is a lot more important to give a complete answer. Rather than stating *"you're doing it wrong"*, explain specifically ***what*** OP is doing wrong and, more importantly, ***why*** is it wrong. Posting code without explaining it is a lot less helpful than explaining the problem and your proposed solution.